# Receive payments with Paypal for my Web app

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a web app on which users can sign up and sell their products.
I want to integrate paypal such that the sellers in my Web app would receive money in their paypal account when buyers choose the option to pay with paypal button.
I want the integration flow to be like what [calendly](https://calendly.com/) has.
I want the sellers to integrate paypal using OAUTH 2.0.

How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do a normal [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), and in the request's `purchase_units` specify a `payee` object with details on what account is to receive the payment.

This is documented in [Send funds to another account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/).

Comment: Is it possible to store credit card and then charge them later ?

Comment: No, not without a different reference transaction or billing agreement or vault v2 integration, which are more complex and which the receiving business account is likely not approved for and will not have access to.

Comment: I want to implement what Calendly has. When I choose connect "paypal to accept payment", it redirects me to `https://www.paypal.com/bizsignup/partner#/checkAccount`. Which API is this and how can I achieve this?